# Query on automating Flink Job submission

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I am trying to use Flink REST APIs to automate Flink job submission process via pipeline. To call any Flink Rest endpoint we should be aware about the Job Manager Web interface IP. For my POC, I got the IP after running flink-yarn-session command on CLI, but what is the way to get it from code?

Fo automation, I am planning to call following REST API in sequence

1. request. get('http://ip-10-0-127-59.ec2.internal:8081/jobs/overview')  // Get Running job Id
2. requests.post('http://ip-10-0-127-59.ec2.internal:8081/jobs/:jobID/savepoints/') // Cancel job with savepoint
3. requests.get('http://ip-10-0-127-59.ec2.internal:8081/jobs/:JobId/savepoints/
   :savepointId') // Get savepoint status
4. requests. Post("http://ip-10-0-127-59.ec2.internal:8081/jars/upload"). // Upload jar for new job
5. requests.post(
   "http://ip-10-0-127-59.ec2.internal:8081/jars/de05ced9-03b7-4f8a-bff9-4d26542c853f_ATVPlaybackStateMachineFlinkJob-1.0-super-2.3.3.jar/run") // submit new job
6. requests.get('http://ip-10-0-116-99.ec2.internal:35497/jobs/:jobId') // Get status of new job

Answer (score 0):

If you have the flexibility to run on Kubernetes instead on Yarn (looks like you are on AWS from your hostnames, so you could use EKS) then I would recommend using the official [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/) - it is built for exactly this purpose by the community.

If Yarn is a given for your use case then you may follow the code examples that Flink uses to talk to the Yarn ResourceManager in the [flink-yarn](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-yarn) package, especially the following:

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-yarn/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/yarn/YarnClusterDescriptor.java#L384
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-yarn/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/yarn/YarnResourceManagerDriver.java#L258